# Where can I find a picture of earth on which I can overlay points?

Tags: mapping, visualization, cartography

Are there any free map pictures I can use for geographical visualizations?  I'm looking for something of reasonable quality I can map lat/lon points to pixels on and play around with visualization techniques.  Where does one go about finding something like this?

Answer (score 0):

**QGIS** is a free and open-source desktop GIS that will be good for this purpose. By adding the free plugin **OpenLayers** (which is a one-click process) you have access to Google Maps, Bing Maps, OpenStreetMap and more as a basemap. These are high quality as you require. Over these you can display any data that you wish to experiment with visualising.

[QGIS download link](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download) ,  [OpenLayers plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com/) API and combine with tiles from OpenStreet Maps . It will allow you to do a lot more.